# ASP.NET MVC: problem connecting to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using this guide:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-7

Like instructed, I entered to `ASP.NET Web Application Administrator`, but when I enter the security tab:

> There is a problem with your selected
>   data store. This can be caused by an
>   invalid server name or credentials, or
>   by insufficient permission. It can
>   also be caused by the role manager
>   feature not being enabled. Click the
>   button below to be redirected to a
>   page where you can choose a new data
>   store.
>
> The following message may help in
>   diagnosing the problem: **Unable to
>   connect to SQL Server database**.

I did clicked the button below, but it didn't help at all.

So far I did exactly (I think..) like the guide said I should.
I have a terrible feeling that the answer is obvious.

**Edit 1:**
BTW, When I open the full solution from the guide and try to open the `ASP.NET Web Application Administrator`, the following error shows up:

> There is a problem with your selected
>   data store. This can be caused by an
>   invalid server name or credentials, or
>   by insufficient permission. It can
>   also be caused by the role manager
>   feature not being enabled. Click the
>   button below to be redirected to a
>   page where you can choose a new data
>   store.
>
> The following message may help in
>   diagnosing the problem: A
>   network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

**Edit 2:**
Connection String:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have SQL server express installed and do you have the database in app_data?

Comment: I have the compact edition, but the DB is not in App_Data. The guide doesn't contain any information about DB creation

Comment: look on your file system for a database named ASPNETDB.MDF - this is required - is that there? Im assuming you have no security configured in the app yet, which is why it works. Post the section from your web.config under <connectionStrings>

Comment: I found the ASPNETDB.MDF file, should I put it in the APP_DATA Directory? I edited my post with the connection string

Comment: try adding this to the <connectionStrings> element            <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: I added the mdf file to the APP_DATA directory and the code you gave me to the connection-string. Now the error changes: **A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)**

Comment: Interesting... Is it possible that the error is caused due the fact that I have `SQL Express` installed along-side `SQL Compact edition`?
Visual studio Shows the same error when I'm trying to add a new database to the APP_DATA folder, and the `SQL Management tool` shows the same error when I'm trying to connect the server

Comment: you should be able to use one or the other as long as autoattach is specified. Since I use express and you have compact, try using the second link here to test a new project/database with compact see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg606540.aspx

Comment: Yep :) Reinstalled it. Working like charm

Comment: I'm having this problem too, but I still am not sure in the exact steps taken to solve the problem after reading the comments.